# finding sequences from small length sequences

Tags: python, sequence

I want to generate a space by using some events in a specific format. Let me explain the problem on a small example.

Assume that I have the events a,b,c,d,e,f. I will have 3-length sequences as an input consisting of these events. From these sequences I want to generate 6-length (number of events) sequences and there will be no repeated elements in the sequence, i.e. every event will be used exactly once. 6-length sequences need to satisfy some rules.(explained on example)

Example:

```
Input: 
list1:['a','b','c']
list2:['c','d','e']
list3:['b','c','d']
list4:['a','c','g']
list5:['f','g','e']
```

List1 describes that, b and c will come after a, and c will come after b in the 6-length sequence, i.e, when the order changes sequence also changes. In the same manner List2 describes that d and e will come after c, and e will come after d. All of the lists will be taken and rules are recorded. After all rules extracted from these sequences, I need to generate 6-length sequence that obeys rules. As an example;

Lets say in our case(for simplicity) inputs are List1,List2 and List3

```
Input: 
list1:['a','b','c']
list2:['c','d','e']
list3:['b','c','d']
```

Then some results for these lists are;

`['a','b','c','d','e']`: it obeys all of the rules from extracted these 3 lists, like b and c comes after a, d and e comes after c, c and d comes after b. İmportant note from here, if c needs to come after a, they do not need to be adjacent in the output sequence(6-length)

It is not guaranteed that 6-length sequence will always exist. Firstly, it needs to be checked that there is at least one such sequence. If not, algorithm should return false. As an example; lets assume our inputs are Lis1, Lis2, Lis3, Lis4 and Lis5.

```
Input: 
list1:['a','b','c']
list2:['c','d','e']
list3:['b','c','d']
list4:['a','c','g']
list5:['e','g','b']
```

a => b => c => g => b it is not possible since b can not come after itself.

I need an algorithm to generate these sequences in Python. I do not have any code for now, because so far I could not think any efficient algorithm. It needs to be very efficient in finding longer length sequences, too.

If the question is not clear, please let me now.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) can be useful there

Comment: I haven't used any graph algorithm before, can you give any references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a starting point:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import tee, izip

list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['c','d','e']
list3 = ['b','c','d']

g = nx.DiGraph()
for items in [list1, list2, list3]:
    a, b = tee(items)
    next(b)
    g.add_edges_from(izip(a, b))

print nx.topological_sort(g)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

This'll raise an exception if the graph contains cycles...

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It worked very well. I editted raising exception part and if there is acyclic it returns false. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your model as [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/) python library will handle all the graph stuff for you.

To generate random 6 element sequences, you can enumerate all the possible sequences and later pick randomly from those with 6-elements

A sketch of the (lousy but working) algorithm:

1. start with the Jon's example - build the graph and ensure that the graph is a DAG
2. P is a vector of nodes, empty at the beginning
3. pick a random node from the graph, add the node to P
4. select a random neighbour node
5. add the new node to P
6. if P has the desired length (10 or 20 or whatever) then P is a valid result.
7. otherwise, go to 4

Comment: As I said in the problem, 6 -length is just for simplicity to explain the question. I will use it more than 10 length, up to 20 or more. So enumerating is not a solution.

Comment: If you don't like enumerating all of them, you can traverse the DAG taking random branches and outputting solutions that meet the length requirement

Comment: How do I do that? Can you give similar examples?

Comment: I will try it. If I can do it, it  will be really faster. Later on i will need to use 100 length. So it is very important having optimized algorithm. Thanks for the answer.